# JQplot Format String

Tags: javascript, jqplot, axis, format-string

Can I please have some help to format the string on the Y Axis that has a '%' sign.

Here is the code for a '$':

```
tickOptions: {formatString: '$%d'}
```

How do I format the string to use a '%' sign as the '%' sign is used as a 'keyword'?

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
tickFormatter = function (format, val) { 
return val+"%";
}
```

And add this option to the plot:

```
axes: {
 yaxis: {
 tickOptions: {
  formatter: tickFormatter
 }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pabloker/9ZrKA/3/

Answer (score 6):

To write a '%' sign you have to double it :

```
axes:
   {yaxis: 
        {tickOptions: 
               {formatString: '%%%d'}
        }
   }
```

`%%%d` will write '%10' if your value is 10.
Similarly, `%d%%` will write '10%' if again your value is 10.
So you just have to replace the '$' sign by '%%'.

Anthony.