# Jqplot formatString for converting axis ticks from thousands to K

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have some working Jqplot charts that I would like to truncate the 3 trailing zeros from numbers when they get into the thousands. For example, my chart would display axis ticks of 1,500, 15,000 and 150,000; but I would like it to say something like 1.5k, 15k, and 150k as the numbers sometimes get too long to display comfortably on my pages containing multiple charts.

I found from previous answers on this site that formatString in Jqplot uses the sprintf function, so I was playing around with some of those conversions listed on http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html but can't seem to get it quite right, but I'm not really familiar with the syntax of using them in a more complex way outside of the simple examples given.

Here is a simple code snippet example using formatString on the Y-Axis right now to insert a thousands separator. This is what I'm wondering can be modified in some way to covert thousands to 'K', or if there's another method I should be looking at.

```
options = {axes:{yaxis:{tickOptions:{formatString: "%'i"}}}}

$.jqplot('example',  [[[1,1000],[2,2000],[3,100000]]], options);
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please.

Comment: I added the relevant jqplot code, leaving out the rest of my unrelated options and html, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out thanks to another post on here discussing formatString ([JQplot Format String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369274/jqplot-format-string_)).

It was suggested that instead of using formatString, that you can simply write your own tick formatter for Jqplot to use, which I wasn't aware of. So I wrote the following to achieve the conversion I was after (ex. 1,000 to 1.0K, 10,000 to 10K, 1,000,000 to 1.0M etc):

```
tickFormatter = function (format, val) {
    if (val >= 1000000) {
        val = val / 1000000;
    return val.toFixed(1)+"M";
    } 
    if (val >= 1000) {
        val = val / 1000;
            if (val < 10) {
                return val.toFixed(1)+"K";
            }
        return val.toFixed(0)+"K";
    }
    return val;
}

options = {axes:{yaxis:{tickOptions:{formatter: tickFormatter}}}}

$.jqplot('example',  [[[1,1000],[2,2000],[3,100000]]], options);
```

I'm fairly new so I'm sure someone more experienced could clean the formatter up a bit. But here's the working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/planetxpress/jPexp/

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a simple adjustment to allow for both positive and negative number formatting

```
                        tickFormatter = function (format, val) {
                        if (val >= 1000000 || val<-1000000) {  ///here
                            val = val / 1000000;
                            return val.toFixed(1)+"M";
                            } 
                        if (val >= 1000 || val<-1000) {  ///and here
                            val = val / 1000;
                                if (val < 10) {
                                    return val.toFixed(1)+"K";
                                }
                            return val.toFixed(0)+"K";
                        }
                        return val;
                    }
```